# Complete code for calling the object of category.java in main activity

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a class name `category.java` in eclipse and I want to display the attributes of this through `mainactivity.java`  by calling the object of `category.java` in `mainactivity.java`.

How can I do this ?

**category.java file**

```
package com.example.tabstest;

public class Catagory {

private int id;
private String name;
private String desc;
private int image;

public Catagory(int id, String name, String desc) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.desc = desc;
}
public Catagory(int id, String name, String desc, int image) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.image = image;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}
public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}
public int getImage() {
    return image;
}
public void setImage(int image) {
    this.image = image;
}

}
```

Comment: create an instance of `Catagory` class and access their attributes.

Comment: i want to call in this file home.java tell me the code how can i do this ..

Comment: `Catagory catagory=new Catagory();` then use `catagory.getName()` etc

Comment: public class Home extends ActivityGroup { ListView l ;
 ArrayList<Catagory> categories = new ArrayList<Catagory>(); 
    TextView name , desc , price ;
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);  
  categories.add( new Catagory(1,"chiken karahi","decp") );
  categories.add( new Catagory(2,"chiken karahi1","decp") );
  categories.add( new Catagory(3,"chiken karahi2","decp") );
  categories.add( new Catagory(4,"chiken karahi3","decp") );
 categories.add( new Catagory(5,"chiken karahi4","decp") );

Comment: please remove code from comment instead add in your question itself.

Answer (score 0):

try following you can access like following way,

write following code in your main activity's onCreate().

```
    ImageView ivImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
    Catagory catagory=new Catagory(1, "abc", "this set value",R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    int id=catagory.getId();
    String name=catagory.getName();
    String desc=catagory.getDesc();
    int image=catagory.getImage();
    Log.v("id", "Id="+id);
    Log.v("name", "Name="+id);
    Log.v("desc", "Desc="+id);
    ivImage.setImageResource(image);
```